# Terminal - packages have been kept back. How to install them?

Tags: package-management, gnome-terminal

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. When I try to upgrade on Terminal. I get the message that some packages have been kept back.

I have attempted to use:
" sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade  "
and
" sudo apt-get install  ".

I inserted the packages which are: apparmor libapparmor1 libapparmor1:i386 python3-software-properties software-properties-common software-properties-gtk.

When I enter either of the above syntax with the list of packages, I get the message that they could not be found. What should I do?

Comment: Nevermind, I retried " sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade " and it worked. Maybe this will help someone else. Have a good day everyone.